# Kafka Stream Join memory keeps growing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, rocksdb

I have some memory issues with a Kafka Stream that joins 2 Streams (one stream enrichs the other one). When the state store grows, the memory used (heap + off heap) grows too, and my application finishes with an OOM. It looks like the Stream keep all the data in memory, in my understanding the state store (and by default rocksdb) was meant to flush some data on disk, am I wrong?

I implemented the BoundedMemoryRocksDBConfig mentionned in the documentation to limit its memory print, but the memory keep growing with the state store (just a little slower but the stream is way slower too, so I don't know if it is effective)

My stream function is quite simple, and I have one input topic and one output topic:

```
public Function<KStream<String, TopicEventModel>, KStream<String, MainObject>> mergeObject() {
return input -> {
    
    final KStream<String, MainObject> mainObjectStream = input
        .filter((key, value) -> filterMain(value.get()))
        .mapValues(this::mapMain);

    final KStream<String, SubObject> subObjectStream = input
            .filter((key, value) -> filterSub(value.get()))
            .mapValues(this::mapSub);

    return mainObjectStream.join(
            subObjectStream,
                (mainObject, subObject) ->
                        Optional.ofNullable(mainObject)
                            .map(main -> {
                                main.setSubObject(subObject);
                                return main;
                            }).orElse(main),
                JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofHours(5)),
                StreamJoined.with(
                    Serdes.String(),
                    Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MainObject.class)),
                    Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(SubObject.class))
                )
        );
}
```

}

Comment: It is not possible to join two streams declaratively in KafkaStreams. You are either joining:
- two KTables
- KStream and a KTable
- KStream and GlobalKTable

Please show your code.

Comment: Hello, you're right I meant a join of 2 KStreams. I added the code, it's a Spring Cloud Stream function

Comment: That leaves the following questions: 
1. Is this the only topology in your application?
2. How much memory has been allocated?

Comment: Yes it is the only topology, and 4 GB are allocated to the stream and there are 30 millon messages to process

Comment: You should easily be able to process this then. For future reference on sizing this is an article which has saved my life a couple of times: https://medium.com/@souquieres.adam/kafka-stream-microservice-sizing-recipe-5eb71131ae67 . Note: 30M messages, if each is almost 1 MB and all land in the 5h window totals up to 30 GB and you are OOM. So it's not impossible to see the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand why it can reach the 4GB if the 30M messages arrives in the time window. The Rocksdb cache is limited and when it exceeds the cache size the data is flushed to disk. To me, the performance can decrease because Rocksdb writes and read a lot from disk, but I don't understand the OOM

Answer (score 1):

The likely candidate here is that the grace window is too large to fit all of your data especially if the topics are "heavy".

If you require a bilateral join (and it seems that way), you could consider the Processor API for this, however you would have to manage the stores yourself.

Another thing is that you seem to be interested in a left-join. Only enriching the main objects. That can be done with stream-table join which might be more efficient and allows you to omit the window aspect of your code for subObjects.

You're probably familiar with this: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Another issue you might be running into is that your application might not have the rights to delete messages from topics (in that case check broker logs), this can be an issue on internal topics.

Personally, if you need a KStream-KStream join I prefer the Processor API, since you are not forced to window there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The KTable is not relevant in my case because of the asymmetric behavior of the KStream/KTable join. I don't control the arrival order of the MainObject/SubObject messages, and I want each MainObject to be processed with its corresponding SubObject. I will take a look to the processor API thanks.

Comment: You'll need two processors then. One for MainObject and one for SubObject stream, and two stores. When a MainObject comes in it will look for a SubOjbect matching and `context.forward`. For SubObject it will be the other way around.